# Ajax и PHP

Tags: ajax, php

Имеется обработчик на php. Он выводит некоторую инофрмацию, в том числе и JS-скрипт, который собственно и не запускается.
Так вот есть ли возможность его запуустить..?

PS. Я раздумывал над вариантом переслать его обратно посредством, json_encode, но как избежать вставки ненужного контента?

Comment: Почему не запускается? а через eval?

а на jquery и вовсе один параметр в запросе.

Answer (score 1):

Более простой способ добавить скрипт минуя ajax.
index.php

```
<BODY>
</BODY>
<SCRIPT>
body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
sc=document.createElement('script');
sc.src='test.js';
body.appendChild(sc);
</SCRIPT>
```

test.js

```
alert('ok');
```

В результате увидим `ok`

Answer (score 1):

для jQuery:
вариант чистый скрипт:

```
  $.post('обработчик.php',function(data){},'script');
```

если скрипт идет вставкой вместе с другими данными но всё же обрамлен тегом `<script>`, тогда можно воспользоваться таким вот костылем (но это очень нехорошо, и хорошие кодеры так не поступают).

```
$.post('обработчик.php',function(data){
$('body').append('<div id="some_id" style="display:none">'+data+'</div>');
$('#some_id').remove();
});
```

в идеале передать в json, скрипт в одной переменной(например script), контент в другой(content), тогда:

```
$.post('обработчик.php',function(data){
 eval(data.script);
},'json');
```

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря не понял сути вопроса, но по поводу элементарно простого добавления JS скриптов посредством того-же javascript

```
$('<script src="/javascriptRoot/script.js"></script>').appendTo( $('head') ) // jQ

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '/javascriptRoot/script.js';
document.head.appendChild( script ); // pure JavaScript
```

Если кого интересует чем этот вариант принципиально отличается от варианта предложенного [@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus) 'ом - спрашивайте, уточню в комментариях.

Как уже писал выше - сути проблемы не понял, но попытаюсь проявить экстрасенсорные способности....

Если вам с сервера приходит скрипт и, например - еще какие-то данные, тогда все тоже довольно просто, например к нас пришел JSON хэш, мы преобразовали в javascript объект и данные поля 'scriptSource' нам нужно выполнить.

```
var data = { scriptSource : 'function check(){ console.log("done") }' };

// непосредственно инициализация скрипт элемента и добавление в head
$("<script></script>").html( data.scriptSource )
  .appendTo( $('head') ) // jQ

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = data.scriptSource;
document.head.appendChild( script ); // pure JS

// в этом примере мы добавили простой скрипт с функцией check
// после того, как скрипт добавлен и разобран
// мы смело можем вызывать эту функцию

check(); // -> done
```

PS: если не то, уточните вопрос

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь. То есть во втором описанным вами способом, не надо прибегать к json_encode? Как я понял запустятся все скрипты что есть в ответе.
Но дело в том,что из БД выводиться 10 постов, к которым прикреплены яндекс-карты. Вот их и надо запустить к каждой записи.